# OpenCV Library for Android (portrait camera)

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing android application with facial recogniton using opencv library. My problem is the screen orientation. I got a solution with code below in JavaCameraView class.

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
```

The camera is good but the facial detection doesnt work.

I found [this](http://littlecheesecake.me/blog/13804736/opencv-android-orientation) but I think that the solution does not work in latest version of opencv library.

Any ideas could be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The problem is "In portrait display the images somehow are rotated 90 deg and stretched a bit" ([link](http://littlecheesecake.me/blog/13804736/opencv-android-orientation)), but the code in this link doesnt work with the latest version of open cv library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to also create the `setDisplayOrientation` by adding this:

```
protected void setDisplayOrientation(Camera camera, int angle){
    Method downPolymorphic;
    try
    {
        downPolymorphic = camera.getClass().getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", new Class[] { int.class });
        if (downPolymorphic != null)
            downPolymorphic.invoke(camera, new Object[] { angle });
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
    }
}
```